# Could not post parameters to Server

Tags: java, php, http

I am trying to pass parameters to a PHP Server using POST method in java but the response string I get is an error message on the line where the server tries to access *option* parameter at line:

`Undefined index at line $option = $_POST["option"];`

My code is as follows:

```
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL("http://--server-ip--")).openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
String urlParameters = "option=1&type=1&coord=-33.867,151.206";
con.setDoOutput(true);
DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
con.connect();
```

Can anybody point out the mistake?

Comment: what does your variable `urlParameters` contain?

Comment: try `var_dump($_POST)`, this will ensure if all the parameters are in there and then find the correct index for your `option` .

Comment: it seems ok, you may have error on your server side. Could you try it with curl `curl -X POST -H "User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0" -H "Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5" http://--server-ip--?option=1&type=1&coord=-33.867,151.206`

Comment: Wouldn't using [Apache HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html) make your life easier?